# Inductive proof of series (sum of 1 / [i*(i+1)] )

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

I like to show that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i(i+1)} = 1 - \frac{1}{n+1} \quad   \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.
$$

This seems to be a possible solution:

Base case:
$$ n_0 = 1 $$
$$ \sum_{i=1}^1 \frac{1}{1*2} = 1 - \frac{1}{1+1}$$
$$ \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2} $$

Induction hypothesis:
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i(i+1)} = 1 - \frac{1}{n+1} $$

Induction step:
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{i(i+1)} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i(i+1)} + \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} $$
with the induction hypothesis
$$ = 1 - \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} \quad (1) $$
$$ = 1 - \frac{(n+2) \color{red}{-1} }{(n+1)(n+2)} \quad (2) $$
$$ = 1 - \frac{n+1}{(n+1)(n+2)} \quad (3) $$
$$ = 1 - \frac{1}{n+2} \quad (4) $$

Now, my problem is that I cannot follow from equation (1) to equation (2). How it comes to "minus 1" in the numerator.
If I do this I come to
$$ 1 - \frac{(n+2) \color{red}{+1} }{(n+1)(n+2)} \quad (2a) $$

Could someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{\color{red}{-1}}{n+1}+\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}=\frac{\color{red}{-1}(n+2)+1}{(n+1)(n+2)}=\color{orange}{-}\frac{(n+2)\color{orange}{-1}}{(n+1)(n+2)}$$

Comment: That means 
$$
1-\frac{1}{n+1} = \frac{-1}{n+1}  \quad ??
$$

Comment: @poetspie No, $$1-\frac1{n+1}=\frac{(n+1)-1}{n+1}=-\frac{1-(n+1)}{n+1}.$$ It can be also simplified to $$\frac{n}{n+1}.$$